# Flex-Box is invisible on FireFox 47

Tags: css, firefox, rendering, flexbox, mozilla

I'm working on this page..

[buiumshow.com/landing](http://buiumshow.com/landing)

I know, the site content is not in english.
but in chrome, ie, safari and even ff for android i can see the social icons bar on the top-right corner.
 for some reason on firefox on my pc (47.0) the flex-box is invisible. when i test it on local enviroment (i.e. not on server) it's working, but on server, with firefox, the social icons flex-box isn't visible.
I've already tried all the other suggestions about display: -moz-box; and flex: 1, and many more solutions i found here, but hadn't come to a solution yet.

**Your kind help will be highly appreciated**

Comment: social icons bar displaying here on FF47...

Comment: Now it's working here as well... though i didn't change nothing. wierd. tnx for your reply :)